# Using Mono as scripting language on Android and iOS

Tags: android, mono, xamarin

I've written game engine in C++ and I would use mono as scripting language (similar to Unity and CryMono), my question is,
am I allowed to dynamic link Mono on Android and iOS and use the runtime for scripting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not allow any kind of dynamic linking / code generation / JIT on device. All the code you execute must be compiled statically into the main binary.

Android is more lax though, and does allow pretty much everything iOS doesn't.